# Is it possible to use container-managed authentication with password salting?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, jaspic

I know how to set up vanilla container-managed security that uses form authentication and uses digested passwords (say, SHA-256). Something like this:

#### web.xml

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>jdbc</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.jsf</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login-error.jsf</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

#### login.xhtml

```
<form action="j_security_check">
    <p><label>
        Username:<br/>
        <input type="text" name="j_username" />
    </label></p>
    <p><label>
        Password:<br/>
        <input type="password" name="j_password" />
    </label></p>
    <p>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </p>
</form>
```

Pretty darn simple - but what I'd *really* like to be able to do is salt the password with a global salt and the username. Yes, I am aware that [this isn't **ideal**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536584/non-random-salt-for-password-hashes/536756#536756) but right now, I'm just building a proof-of-concept.

Can the container (GlassFish 3, in this case) do this for me, or do I have to [write my own login filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470591/basic-security-in-jsf/1484398#1484398)? I've done it before (for J2EE applications) but my gut tells me that there's got to be a tighter way to do it now that I'm using Java EE 6.

Comment: Is anyone else surprised that all the default security realms neglect to salt the password? And that there still doesn't seem to be a simple way to get the passwords salted apart from rolling your own login module?

Answer (score 3):

I get the feeling you're looking for a quick (& potentially dirty?) way to modify the build-in authentication provider.

The proper way to go is to implement your own Java Authentication Service Provider for the new JASPIC API ([JSR-196](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr196/index.html)).  It is more laborious, but this method lets you roll your implementation any way you like it, and it should be compatible with any Java EE 6 application server.

For a basic authentication scheme with password salting, implementing such a provider should be pretty straightforward.  You will have to think about managing users and passwords, but one solution could be to let your provider re-use the users defined in the Glassfish authentication realms, so that you only have to manage the custom salted passwords yourself.

There's a nice tutorial for WebSphere, which you should be able to adapt for Glassfish [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/beta/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/tsec_jaspi_develop.html).

Comment: The WebSphere tutorial has moved: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.zseries.doc%2Finfo%2Fzseries%2Fae%2Ftsec_jaspi_develop.html