# JSF - implementing filter for restricted pages

Tags: java, security, jsf, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I'm following answer by @BalusC to [JSF 2.0: How to get the URL that is entered in the browser's address bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105263/jsf-2-0-how-to-get-the-url-that-is-entered-in-the-browsers-address-bar) to restrict pages from users who are not logged in.

Filter:

```
public class RestrictPageFilter implements Filter{
    FilterConfig fc;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        fc=filterConfig;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpreq = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpres = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        if (httpreq.getUserPrincipal() == null) {
            httpreq.getSession().setAttribute("from", httpreq.getRequestURI());
            httpres.sendRedirect("/pages/login.xhtml");
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Admin pages</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
      <url-pattern>/restricted/*</url-pattern>
      <http-method>GET</http-method>
          <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>

  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>User pages</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/restricted/*</url-pattern>
      <http-method>GET</http-method>
          <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
      <role-name>USER</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>

   <!--login-config>
     <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
     <realm-name>jdbc-realm</realm-name>
     <form-login-config>
       <form-login-page>/pages/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
       <form-error-page>/pages/error.xhtml</form-error-page>
     </form-login-config>
   </login-config-->

    <filter>
        <filter-name>RestrictPageFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>gov.denis.chanceryweb5.filter.RestrictPageFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>RestrictPageFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/restricted/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

glassfish-web.xml

```
<glassfish-web-app>
<security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
    <group-name>ADMIN</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
  <security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>USER</role-name>
    <group-name>USER</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
```

realm in glassfish gui console:
[image]

When accessing my web app, in browser i see this for some reason? why?

[image]

Comment: Don't know if this is related to "authentication" thing but your filter shouldn't be mapped on all pages with *.xhtml (it gets called on every page including index). You should map it only on restricted pages which I suppose index is not.

Comment: so i should move `login.xtml` out of pages i want to restrict?

Comment: Login pages should be out of security contraints. What does your database tables look like? You already had them and is trying to adapt it to JDBCRealm in GlassFish?

Comment: @Melissaa yes and you can acomplish that by changing your filter mapping to something like <url-pattern>/restricted/*</url-pattern> depending on the location of your restricted pages. index.xhtml should be in some "public" folder or simply outside the restricted folder.

Comment: Moved login page out of restricted pages. problem persists :(

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing the dialog associated with the BASIC authentication method.

You currently have the login-config elements of your web.xml file commented out... so that configuration is not being applied.

GlassFish 3 servers have a default login-config that is used when a user deployed app specifies a security-constraint but does not specify a login config...

The effective login-config for your app actually looks something like this

```
  <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>file</realm-name>
  </login-config>
```

The default login-config is specified in `glassfish3/glassfish/domains/<your domain name here>/config/default-web.xml`

Comment: Thanks for answer. I commented out login-config because answer to the question i linked says i need to replace it with filter. So its wrong?

Comment: @Melissaa : I have never known BalusC to provide an answer that was incorrect when the server is Tomcat. Unfortunately, each server is allowed to 'add value' in areas that aren't regulated by the specs.  This is an area where TC and GF differ. If you want to have GlassFish behave like Tomcat (in this particular area), you can remove the default login-config element from config/default-web.xml.

Comment: i commented out default login-config. But it looks like `request.login(name, pass)` does not work without `login-config` in web.xml

Comment: @Melissa Did you redeploy the app after you edited the config/default-web.xml file?