# JSF PostConstruct Exception Handling - Redirect

Tags: exception, jsf-2, postconstruct

I'd like to handle a JSF @PostConstruct exception by redirecting to another page.  I'm using `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().dispatch("page.jsf");` which works great but since the page uses 2 backing beans it continues to load the other backing bean (and if it encounters an error on the other backing bean it never gets to that dispatch/redirect).  My question is.. is there a way to force that dispatch to happen right away and not load everything else?

Answer (score 4):

Look at this similar question:
[JSF navigation redirect to previous page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164964/jsf-navigation-redirect-to-previous-page)

According to BalusC you can use the following instead of dispatch:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(url);
```

Or, in order to stop rendering the current page, put

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
```

Regards

Comment: The key aspect that this doesn't cover is that it still tries to process the entire bean.

Comment: @monkey-wrench What do you mean by 'tries to process the entire bean'?. if you add a return statement  after the redirect then the postconstruct method will end, are you talking about this?