# Redirecting in @PostConstruct method resulted in IllegalStateException

Tags: redirect, jsf-2, illegalstateexception

According to the [answer of BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1930907/801434), I used

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(url);
```

in my `@PostConstruct` method to stop JSF from rendering the view and redirect users. However, when I try to run the code, I still ran into the `java.lang.IllegalStateException` exception at the above line.

```
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendRedirect(ResponseFacade.java:524)
    at StudentManagedBean.CourseSummary.init(CourseSummary.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

**UPDATE:** I added the following line in my `@PostConstruct` method:

```
System.out.println("INIT " + FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().isResponseCommitted());
```

and what I saw was `INIT true`. I wonder if the response is supposed to be committed BEFORE the `@PostConstruct` method is called?

I'd be very grateful if you could give me an advice.

Comment: I am pretty sure that even if the Response has been completed in PostConstruct then the rest of the JSF lifecycle will still be executed.  Do you get an error doing this from the constructor instead?  Is this an Ajax request?  What JSF implementation and version are you using?

Comment: I'm using JSF 2.0. Besides, I must do it in `@PostConstruct` because I need to call a function from my EJB before redirecting. It's not an AJAX request too.

Comment: The response is committed because the response header has already been manipulated by the FacesServlet.  This is different than the response being completed which means the body has been written to and finalized which doesn't happen until the Render phase.  Redirecting at any point after the response has been committed will result in an IllegalStateException so your only choice is to forward.

Comment: This was properly addressed in [another answer of BalusC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168043/redirect-in-postconstruct-causes-illegalstateexception)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my update, the following line printed `INIT true`:

```
System.out.println("INIT " + FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().isResponseCommitted());
```

I finally found why the above situation occurred. On my page, before the `ManagedBean X`, which contains the redirect function, was referenced by `UIComponent A`, another `ManagedBean Y` was referenced beforehand by `UIComponent B` that is placed above `UIComponent A` in the page structure. As a consequence, the response was partially committed by `ManagedBean Y`, which makes it impossible for `ManagedBean X` to send a `redirect` request.

Answer (score 2):

A redirect will not work here, because even though the response has been completed and finalized, JSF is not smart enough to avoid its typical routine of running through the lifecycle events anyway.

Instead you can try doing a Forward from a RequestDispatcher.  A Forward is different from a redirect in the following ways:

- Performed internally by the servlet
- Browser is apathetic
- original url stays intact

Here is some code that displays how this can be done...

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher =
    ((ServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest())
    .getRequestDispatcher("/j_spring_security_logout");

try {
  dispatcher.forward((ServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest(),
  (ServletResponse) context.getExternalContext().getResponse());
} catch (ServletException e) {
  log.error("ServletException", e);
} catch (IOException e) {
  log.error("IOException", e);
}
```

By doing this you are ending the execution of the FacesServlet prematurely and forwarding it onto a different servlet altogether.  I imagine that from this other servlet it might be possible to redirect to the desired location.

Comment: :( Is this this the only way to achieve what I want? Creating a new servlet seems a bit too much for the simple redirection that I need.