# Navigate to a different page in preRenderViewEvent depending on user permission; ExternalContext#dispatch() does not work

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

The page should be rendered only if user has permissions to see it. I try to achieve that by performing a check in PreRenderView event listener method:

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{theBean.init}" />
```

And the method itself:

```
public void init() {
    if (user.havePermission()) {
        // backing bean init
    } else {
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();
        ec.getRequestMap().put("message", no_permissions_message);
        try {
            ec.dispatch(ec.getRequestContextPath()
                + path_to_no_perm_page);
            fc.responseComlete();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to look at denied page I see it, but get an exception in server log:

```
at org.omnifaces.util.FacesLocal.getRequestMap(FacesLocal.java:945) [omnifaces-1.7.jar:1.7]
at org.omnifaces.util.FacesLocal.getRequestAttribute(FacesLocal.java:953) [omnifaces-1.7.jar:1.7]
at org.omnifaces.util.Faces.getRequestAttribute(Faces.java:1416) [omnifaces-1.7.jar:1.7]
at org.omnifaces.eventlistener.CallbackPhaseListener.getCallbackPhaseListeners(CallbackPhaseListener.java:110) [omnifaces-1.7.jar:1.7]
at org.omnifaces.eventlistener.CallbackPhaseListener.afterPhase(CallbackPhaseListener.java:77) [omnifaces-1.7.jar:1.7]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleAfterPhase(Phase.java:189) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:107) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:98) [primefaces-4.0.7.jar:4.0.7]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
...
```

The cause: immediately after dispatch call, FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() returns null. But this don't interrupt current phase. So on the phase end PhaseListener is executed. It tries to get FacesContext instance, but gets null.

Can I avoid PhaseListener execution here?
Or may be check for FacesContext current instance is not null should be added to omnifaces?

Thanks.

Comment: Make this line `fc.responseComlete();` the last line in the `try...catch` block. There is a misspelled which won't compile. (OmniFaces has got nothing to do with the exception).

Comment: I tried both cases. Nothing changed. Seems both should work fine. With `responseComplete()` we just interrupting JSF lifecycle, but not commiting the response, aren't we?

Comment: I corrected it as you say. Thanks. According to the docs this is more right way. Even if both work fine.

Comment: You are dispatching/forwarding using `ExternalContext#dispatch("/path/to/resource");` (404 is likely - I did not concentrate much yesterday). If you need to restrict access (when authorization (permission check) fails), you should conditionally redirect to a public resource using `ExternalContext#redirect("/path/to/resource");`. In both the cases, `FacesContext#responseComplete();` is completely unnecessary. Do you somehow need it in your real application? Besides, if you are on JSF 2.2, then `<f:event type="preRenderView" .../>` may better be replaced with `<f:viewAction action="..." .../>`.

Comment: Yes, I need it in real application. I want to use dispatch because I want not to change URL in client's browser.

Comment: `FacesContext#responseComplete();` is needed here. I tried to remove it and got an Illegal state exception then. Thanks for viewAction, i'll consider it's usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use [`ExternalContext#dispatch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#dispatch-java.lang.String-), ever. This method has no single sensible use case in a decent JSF web application. It only corrupts the JSF life cycle because it creates another `FacesContext` within the current request. You should use JSF's own [`NavigationHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/application/NavigationHandler.html) or use [`ExternalContext#redirect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#redirect-java.lang.String-).

When you're already on JSF 2.2, use `<f:viewAction action="#{bean.init}">` which supports a navigation case outcome (like `<h:commandButton action>`):

```
public String init() {
    // ...
    return "someViewId";
}
```

Or when you're still on JSF 2.0/2.1, and can thus only use `<f:event type="preRenderView">`, and given that you're using OmniFaces use its [`Faces#navigate()`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/util/Faces.html#navigate-java.lang.String-) or [`Faces#redirect()`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/util/Faces.html#redirect-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-):

```
public void init() {
    // ...
    Faces.navigate("someViewId");
}
```

In case you aren't using OmniFaces, here's how it's implemented:

```
public void init() {
    // ...
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.getApplication().getNavigationHandler().handleNavigation(context, null, "someViewId");
}
```

Note that this all may still fail when using `@PostConstruct` instead of `f:viewAction` or `preRenderView`. See also a.o. [Redirect in @PostConstruct causes IllegalStateException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168043/redirect-in-postconstruct-causes-illegalstateexception).